# Allow other developers to QA my code before pushing into main trunk?

Tags: git, version-control, git-extensions

I've been working on a number of different project files, some new and some old. Is there a usual/normal/acceptable method of staging a checkin so that other developers can take a look and QA the code?

I don't want to fully commit/checkin the code as some of it is half baked, but would like some other developers to take a look...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can commit to a different branch, and then merge into `master` when the code has been tested by others.

Your workflow:

```
git checkout -b my_new_feature # create a new branch 'my_new_feature' and switch to it
git add . # add all files to staging area
git commit -m "Add my new feature" # commit the change
git push origin my_new_feature # push this branch to 'origin'
```

Their workflow:

```
git pull origin
git checkout origin/my_new_feature
```

After the code is tested

```
git checkout master
git merge my_new_feature
```

Comment: Thanks for that - certainly sounds like what I'm trying to achieve. From my workflow's point of view, is this what's happening: Create a new branch called my_new_feature Add a reference to everything from this directory (and subdirectories?) into my_new_feature Commit everything into the branch... Not sure if I follow 100% though... could you explain the first 4 steps if you don't mind? :)

Comment: "checkout -b my_new_feature" creates a new branch called my_new_feature and switches over to ti, "git add ." and "git commit" is the author's way of saying "make your edits and commit them", and "git push origin my_new_feature" means send my latest changes to the remote repository that the other devs have access to.

Comment: @plenderj, I've added the explanations. Thanks Alex.

Answer (score 0):

You can commit your code to a feature branch, and publish the branch. This allows all the other devs to pull a copy and switch to it for local review, without affecting their own code. Git Flow is a good example of this:

[`http://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/`](http://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/)

Comment: They can use `git diff -p development..incomingFeature` to see a patch list of just the changes between your new pushed branch and the development branch. That's a quick way to isolate just your new code for review.